# How can I capture the pressed button of a MessageBox from a different thread?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a module in which I have a class which extends this from QMesaageBox in order to more clearly create a new alert, this module contains the following code

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox


class MainMessage(QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self,title,text,buttons):
        super(MainMessage,self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setText(text)
        self.button_list = buttons

    def add_btn(self):
        for button_add in self.button_list:
            self.addButton(button_add)

    def info(self):
        self.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
```

Later I use this code in another module which is the main one, in which I am working with functions that are from another thread and in one of them I call a message

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import  QtCore
from main_message import  MainMessage
import time
class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self,func):
        super(MyThread,self).__init__()

        self.function_list = func

    def run(self):
        for function_to_exec in self.function_list:
            function_to_exec()

class Main(QMainWindow):
    messageSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str,str,list)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main,self).__init__()

        self.resize(800,600)

        self.function_list = [
            self.function_one,
            self.function_two
        ]

        self.message = MainMessage
        self.messageSignal.connect(self.show_message)
        self.btn_pressed = None

        self.start()

    def start(self):
        self.main_thread=MyThread(self.function_list)
        self.main_thread.start()

    def function_one(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        self.messageSignal.emit("ok","ok",[QMessageBox.Ok])
        print(self.btn_pressed)
        if self.btn_pressed == QMessageBox.Ok:
            print("ok btn")
        print("fun_one finish")

    def function_two(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        print("fun_two finish")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str,str,list)
    def show_message(self,tittle,text,buttons):
        new_message = self.message(tittle,text,buttons)
        new_message.info()

        self.btn_pressed = m.exec_()



app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

Now my problem is on the line `if self.btn_pressed == QMessageBox.Ok: print("ok btn")`

Since I am not able to get the button pressed by the user in the qmessagebox

How could I get the button pressed by the user to be able to validate his answer?

**UPDATE - Summary of what I hope to do**

What I'm looking for is that in the function_one I can read or get the value of the button that the user presses in the QMessageBox that I call through a signal emitted from the same function

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve.  Using single letters as variable names makes code difficult to read.  Please provide a better explanation of the issue

Comment: @Alexander,What I'm looking for is that in function_one I can read or get the value of the button that the user presses in the QMessageBox that I call via a signal from that same function

Comment: That doesn't help all that much because the way your code is set up is convoluted.  The way you have it set up right now, I cannot think of a way to get the value of the button in the function one.  This is why you would probably be better off describing the full problem... like why you are trying to get the value of the button in function one and what you plan to do with it.  That way better alternatives can be suggested.